# HLS Audio Streaming Server on Ubuntu

Tags: audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

I want to build a music streaming server that uses HLS to stream to all platforms (desktop, iOS, and Android). I used Flash Media Server on Windows before for video streaming and it was great. This time I am trying to build something similar to what Spotify Streaming is doing to serve on-demand to all platforms with auto adjust bitrate. What are the best free options to achieve that on a Ubuntu box?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best free option is VLC or ffmpeg. If it works for you - download the source and integrate it into your product:

https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Streaming_for_the_iPhone/